# How can I gain humanity in Dark Souls?

Tags: dark-souls

Every so often I'll look up at my counter and notice I gained some humanity. If I was fighting bosses I wouldn't think much of it, but sometimes it will happen when I'm just farming enemies.

I've recently noticed that every so often I will spawn at a bonfire (after dying) and will gain a humanity. I'm uncertain as to why.

In what ways can I gain humanity in Dark Souls?

Comment: I haven't played this game yet, but I was under the impression that some enemies just dropped it (like souls).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From (one of) the [Dark Souls wiki](http://darksoulswiki.wikispaces.com/Humanity):

> - Humanity can be earned by playing as a Phantom, and help kill the
>     end-level boss.
> - Humanity can be earned by killing Evil Spirits
>     (invading players), or by invading and killing a player in another
>     world.
> - Humanity can be bought from some merchants.
> - Humanity can be
>     found, as a dropped item, from some killed enemies.
> - Humanity can be
>     found as a consumable item.
> - Humanity can be earned by having your hint sign up-voted by another player.
> - Humanity can be earned by killing a large amount of monsters in one area if the boss is alive (up to 10 Humanity).

The last reason must be why I was gaining humanity when spawning.

Comment: Your answer doesn't satisfy me. I did just 17th character in Dark Souls to investigate this case and 1 time I finish Undead Parish with only 2 humanity, the other time with 6. And there's no visible pattern because every1 of my characters finished it's way without any death killing ALL enemies in the way (including Dark Knights and minibosses)

Comment: @Marrond I'm having trouble making out what you are trying to say, but humanity has a chance of dropping from some enemies, it's not guaranteed. This means if you did multiple runs through an area you are very likely to get a different number of souls every time.

Comment: @Marrond The wiki link also states that you can gain humanity if one of your hint is up voted and if you kill a large number of monster in an area where the boss is still alive (dying does not reset this counter). Could this explain the difference?

Comment: You have to farm enemies a considerable amount of time before any real ammounts of humaity are gained its a very random drop

Answer (score 1):

I been having this happened too me too. At first I thought it was one of my rings but after some testing some things its not. Could you perhaps be in the covenant the way of white or the white way, w/e it's called? I stopped gaining random humanity after leaving that covenant.

To answer your question about gaining humanity at the bonfire after dying; I have only been able to confirm gaining humanity at the catacombs while I have 00. It happened to me every other death. My guess is its a zone thing, maybe something to do with area bosses as long as there's a bonfire for that area?

I haven't been able to confirm that outside the catacombs.

I also thought maybe its a mob thing or time. after dying from the titanite demon in the catacombs, its been giving me humanity every other death. so i tried this out in anor londo and died by the same giant there (I confirmed time was not a factor with the demon). It wasn't working in anor but I also killed the area boss. and that's as far as I've gotten. not a lot to go on but I want to believe it has something to do with the development throughout the game, if you die too many times before you get to the boss and your out of humanity why not give you a freebie so you can luckily find someone to summon to help?

Comment: Hello, Fewd, and welcome to Gaming.Stackexchange! This answer, as posted, doesn't really answer the question posed by the OP. Would you care to expand your answer to better reflect the OP's question about how to gain humanity? As it is now, something like this would seem better as a comment, rather than its own answer.

Comment: I am in the way of white actually, so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: Thanks raven next time it will be just comments since i dont have the answer, i didnt see the add comment button at first so i just clicked the answer button lol.

Comment: @Fewd: You're still able to comment, and if you feel your answer is not an answer, you're able to delete it; which might be a good idea, so you don't keep collect downvotes; fyi, I didn't downvote, but downvoting non-answers is a good reason to downvote an answer.

Comment: @blunders: thanks for the tip. i know i can delete it but i already took the time and effort to put it up. as it might be a good idea to delete it if i just collect downvotes. im not going to delete it. well anyways i appreciate it. =)